# Why does my TRegEx with case insensitivity not match anything?

Tags: regex, delphi

I have a problem when I use TRegEx with a case insensitive Regex string. The Regex does not match anything.

My regex:

```
'/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&/i'
```

source:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
    regex : TRegEx;
    exper : string;
    fmatch : TMatchCollection;
    example: string;
begin
    example := 'Stream_Map=TestMatch&' 
    exper := '/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&/i';
    regex := TRegEx.Create(exper);
    fmatch := regex.Matches(example);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(fmatch.Count));
end;
```

The matches count shows "0" .

Comment: "... not working as it have to be" What, exactly, is your expected output?

Comment: `TRegEx` is known to work. Since you won't tell us what your regex is meant to do, and what input you feed it, there's no way we can help.

Comment: @David i told that i want to find download links for youtube video and the matches count show "0"!!

Comment: A good question would include the regex (yours does) and the input that you try to match the regex against. Your question omits that part. Unless you tell us what is in `Memo1.Text` we cannot possibly help. Please improve the question to add what is missing.

Comment: @David Memo1.text contain the source code of the youtube video page, I updated my question

Comment: We don't want to download that. Why make us do that? Include it in your question. Well, best of all would be to include just a small part of it, enough to illustrate what the problem is. Then explain what you expect your program to do, and how it fails to meet that expectation. Give the expected match count, which text you expect to match, and give the actual match count.

Comment: @David i update my question with what Memo1.Text contain

Comment: There is nothing in that text that matches `/stream_map`. The only incidence of `stream_map` is not preceeded by a slash `/`. Looks like you are mixing in Perl regex syntax.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ah that's what I expected becuase I used this regex in PHP and it was working fine, but how it will look like in delphi?

Comment: Parsing HTML with Regular expressions is a TERRIBLE idea.

Comment: @WarrenP is there any alternative way to do that?

Comment: Yes, use an HTML/XML parser!

Comment: Read the documentation for `TRegex` to learn the regex syntax.

Comment: You need `'stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&'` for your regex. And pass `[roIgnoreCase]` to `TRegEx.Create`. Like this: `regex := TRegEx.Create(expr, [roIgnoreCase])`

Comment: When I cast the first close vote, this was not a real question. But the edits to the question mean that it is a real question now. Once the question is fixed, we should stop voting to close. In fact, I wish SO would allow me to rescind close votes.

Comment: Good. I'm glad we could help. I'm sorry the question was closed. To begin with it was poor, but to your credit you did everything that was asked of you and improved it. That said, if I had looked more closely at the regex, right from the start, the answer would have been clear to me.

Comment: @David, now that the question has been reopened perhaps you could post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks to me as though you are using the wrong syntax for your regex.

```
'/stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&/i'
```

looks like Perl regex syntax.

For Delphi's `TRegEx` you need to remove the slash delimiters and specify case insensitivity through an options parameter. Like this:

```
regex := TRegEx.Create('stream_map=(.[^&]*?)&', [roIgnoreCase]);
```

Comment: +1. Actually this is a good question now that I see the answer.  I think the question needs FURTHER fixing. Edited it.